# How to communicate with child components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component `VideoPlayer` that conditionally renders one of many different video player providers (think videoJS, JW player, etc.) - so `VideoJSPlayer`, `JWPlayer`, etc.

The parent component monitors when a video has completed and needs to let the child component know it is time to play a new video. Each different video provider has a different JS library / API that I may be referencing. The parent component also renders shared components like a Play button, a Skip button, etc.

How can I most easily have the parent component maintain similar functionality and ensure the child components only handle the library-specific actions?

For example, if the shared Skip button is clicked, how should I call that from the parent? I'm currently using `postMessage()` but it doesn't feel quite right.

Here's some minimal code. Realistically there is more than one thing being maintained and shared by the Parent component.

```
class Player extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      props.videos,
      activeIndex: 0,
      activeVideo: props.videos[0]
    }
  }

  loadNextVideo() {
    // how to communicate to VideoJSPlayer and JWPlayer?
  }

  render() {
    const playerCode = this.props.playerCode
    return (
      <div>
        {
          playerCode === 'videojs' ?
            <VideoJSPlayer/> :
            playerCode === 'jwplayer' ? 
            <JWPlayer/> : null
        }
        <SkipButton
          activeVideo={this.state.activeVideo}
          onClick={() => this.loadNextVideo()}/>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide us the code, so we would be able to help you better.

Comment: @AminDarian sure - I've updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, using state might be the right thing here:

```js
class Parent extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            isPlaying: false,
            seconds_passed : 0,
        }
    }
    handleTimePass(current_time){
        this.setState({
            seconds_passed: current_time
        })
    }
    handlePause(){
        this.setState({
            isPlaying: false
        })
    }
    handleResume(){
        this.setState({
            isPlaying: true
        })
    }
    render(){
        return <div>
            <Player handleSetTime={this.handleTimePass} isPlaying={this.state.isPlaying}/>
            <OptionPanel 
                 isPlaying={this.state.isPlaying}
                 handleStop={this.handlePause}
                 handleResume={this.handleResume}
            />
        </div>
    }
}
```

Now your player and Option components can call a prop function that changes parent state and that changed state again gets passed to other child components

```js
const Player = props => {
    return <div>
        <YourPlayerLibrary setTime={props.handleSetTime} playingStatus={props.isPlaying} />
    <div>
}
```

and

```js
const Options = props => {
    return <div>
        <button onClick={props.handleStop}>stop</button>
        <button onClick={props.handleResume}>resume</button>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start pointing out some poor patterns:

- derived state from props (props.videos);

you for most time should not duplicate props to state;

- derived state from other state (activeVideo);

`activeVideo` is not a necessary state. it's a computed value derived from `activeIndex` and `props.videos`. It's a redundant state, you only need to keep store the reference of current video;

And some small tips;

- `constructor` is not necessary for some years, you can declare your state directly outside;
- declaring your methods as arrow functions is a practical and cleaner way to bind `this`;

Given that, your `loadNextVideo` would update to the next index. `VideoJSPlayer` and `JWPlayer` should receive as props `activeVideo` and `loadNextVideo` that should be called in these components when the video is done playing;

```
class Player extends React.Component {

  state = {
    activeIndex = 0
  }

  loadNextVideo = () => {
    // you might add some validation if it's the last index
    if (this.props.videos.length - 1 === this.state.activeIndex) return  
    this.setState(({ activeIndex }) => ({ activeIndex: activeIndex + 1 }))
  }

  render() {
    const { activeIndex } = this.state
    const activeVideo = this.props.videos[activeIndex]
    const playerCode = this.props.playerCode
    return (
      <div>
        {
          playerCode === 'videojs' ?
            <VideoJSPlayer activeVideo={ activeVideo } loadNextVideo={ this.loadNextVideo } /> :
            playerCode === 'jwplayer' ? 
            <JWPlayer activeVideo={ activeVideo } loadNextVideo={ this.loadNextVideo } /> : null
        }
        <SkipButton
          activeVideo={ this.state.activeVideo }
          onClick={ this.loadNextVideo }/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```